# What image generation libraries for PHP should I use?

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd, libraries

I am going to create some images with text using PHP script and want to simplify the process.

Are there any classes/libraries/wrappers for GD and ImageMagick that can help me with this? For example, add some effects, custom fonts, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

This will help you : http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

`imageloadfont` function can be used to load new fonts refer : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageloadfont.php

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using SVG for this. Text items and effects such as blur can be added very easily with simple XML manipulation, and then you could render it with `inkscape` - in PNG or PDF format.